# Hide elements if user is not logged in Omeka

Tags: php

I am trying to hide some elements that are in an array based on if a user is logged in or not. For instance, if a user is not logged in, I don't want them to be able to view the "subject" element.

In my items folder in the show.php file, there is a line of code that I think needs to be edited.

```
<?php echo all_element_texts('item'); ?>
```

Is there a way to use something like

```
if current user display element else hide?
```

Thanks

Comment: hum... you need to provide more information if you wants some help, what the `all_element_texts('item')` does ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this code from Jeremey Boggs

```
<?php

/**
* Unset elements if there is not current authenticated user.
*/
function filter_elements($elementsBySet) {

/* An array of elements in sets to be hidden from non-authenticated users. */
$hiddenElements = array(
    'Dublin Core' => array(
        'Description',
        'Creator'
    )
);

if (!current_user()) {
    foreach ($hiddenElements as $setName => $elementNames) {
        foreach ($elementNames as $elementName) {
            unset($elementsBySet[$setName][$elementName]);
        }
    }
}

return $elementsBySet;
}

add_filter('display_elements', 'filter_elements');
```